# Typescript is generating code for imports which isn't working client-side

Tags: typescript, bower, client-side-scripting

I'm trying a very simple example using bower and the moment library.

In my .ts file I have

```
import * as moment from "./bower_components/moment/moment";
```

which generates

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var moment = require("./bower_components/moment/moment");
```

which fails to work in the browser.

I'm working around this by using the import for debugging than changing it to

```
declare const moment: any;
```

for deployment.

In the Index.html file I have

```
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

I realize that there are a slew of tools to package this all together but I want to make sure I get this simple case working so I understand what is going on.

What am I doing wrong and what is the simplest "proper" way to use bower models client side.

(Later I can get into Npm vs. Bower vs. Browsify, webpack, gulp, grunt and the rest of the menagerie)

Comment: I have tried other module settings and each has its own problem.

Comment: you have to be using a module loader in order to load the code on the client side, maybe look into SystemJs.?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the various module loaders but first want to get the simple case to work. Is there a way to get Typescript to not get in my way so I can explicitly load modules in HTML. Yes, not idea, but a starting point.

As to module loaders -- what is a glide path rather than a learning curve?

Comment: if your code is generated to be loaded by a module loader you can't just put it in a script tag.  I made a very simple example for a training once, you can see it here.  https://github.com/Toskv/talk.timjs.typescript/tree/master/modules/live

Comment: As for the starting point, google is the place to be. :)

Comment: OK -- I managed to use browsify to bundle things up ... other useful info at https://www.slant.co/topics/1089/viewpoints/7/~client-side-javascript-module-loaders~system-js.

Answer (score 0):

> but I want to make sure I get this simple case working so I understand what is going on.

`import` doesn't work in the browser natively right now so the  following

```
import * as moment from "./bower_components/moment/moment";
```

is wrong unless you use a module bundler.

## More

- If you *want to use modules* use a module bundler e.g. webpack quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html

Comment: Thanks. I got browserify to work but I will look into Webpack.